# Issues giving role to the bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot to change its own role. Currently I am just trying to give it a role.

```
import json
import discord
import os
import bs4
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re
from string import digits, ascii_letters
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import aiohttp
from discord.utils import get

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
bot.remove_command('help')
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

url = "hidden"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print("It's ready - fetching btc price")
    while True:
        async with bot.session.get(url) as resp:
            resp = await resp.text()
            auth = [MY BOTS ID]
            role = [ROLE ID, I.E 9234824234626534]
            await bot.add_roles(auth, role)
```

error `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`

How can I give my bot a role or remove a role? It must be in def on_ready()

Comment: Hi, no of course not. I said only must work in on_ready(), not on_member_join

Comment: Oh, sorry! ----

Answer (score 1):

To add roles, you need the `member` object. To get this, you need to know the guild that the member is in, so this would be impossible in `on_ready()` unless you wanted to iterate through every single guild in the guild cache (`for guild in bot.guilds:` if you're really interested in doing that, but still be sure to read the rest of this).

First off, to even be able to obtain a `member` object, you need to have your [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents) enabled. You can do this by just changing your `bot` ClientUser to `commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = discord.Intents.all())`, as well as enabling your intents enabled on the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

For the example that I'll show you I will be using a command, but if you really want to use the `on_ready()` function you can by just replacing every `ctx.guild` with `guild` as you iterate through the guild cache as seen above. I also used the `discord.utils.get` method to define my role, any method that you use is fine so long as you end up with a [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) object

```
@bot.command()
def addRole(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Role Name")
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(bot.user.id)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```